# Can you replace a tautology with a propositional variable?

Tags: proof-verification, logic, propositional-calculus, substitution

Is ~((A v ~A) v M) a substitution instance of ~(P v Q)?

I am under the impression that it is not, since (A v ~A) is a tautology. This results in ~(True v M), which is always false; whereas in the case of ~(P v Q), there is a possibility of the expression evaluating as True (When P and Q are both False).

However, someone else is telling me that since P is a universal proposition variable, that you can simply replace (A v ~A) with P, which leaves ~(P v M) - a perfectly valid substitution instance.

Which is the case? Can you, or can you not, simply replace a tautology with a variable P?

Comment: You are correct, you cannot.

Comment: @AndrewTawfeek It is good to know that I'm not going crazy. Is there something else I'm missing though? Because the answer sheet the professor gave us claims that the two are substitution instances of each other.

Comment: The rule is: you can replace a sentential variable $P$ with a formula $\mathcal A$, but not vice versa (as your example shows) and the reason is exactly what you have stated: to a sentential variable we can assign every truth value.

Comment: You have a terminological issue. $\neg((A\lor\neg A)\lor M)$ *is* a substitution instance of $\neg(P\lor Q)$. You have the meaning of "substitution instance" backwards. A substitution instance of a formula containing propositional (meta-)variables is what you get by replacing those (meta-)variables with formulas. So $\neg((A\lor\neg A)\lor M)$ is a substitution instance of  $\neg(P\lor Q)$ via the substitution $[P\mapsto A\lor\neg A,Q\mapsto  M]$. It's $\neg(P\lor Q)$ that's not a substitution instance of $\neg((A\lor\neg A)\lor M)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I see - you and Derek have made it clear that my issue was thinking that substitution instances are two way relationships. I understand now that they don't substitute both ways. If you make that an answer, I will accept it. Thanks for clearing it up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't validly replace a tautology with a propositional variable, no.  If you did so, then you could pass from a true formula to a formula which has some instance where it is false.  Passing from the true to the false is pretty much the definition of invalidity.

On the other hand ~((A v ~A) v M) is a substitution instance of ~(P v Q).  We simply substitute P with (A v ~A) and Q with M in ~(P v Q) to obtain ~((A v ~A) v M).  Substitution instances need not have the same truth status as their parent formulas.  It uses well-established terminology to say that

~((A v ~A) v (A v ~A)) is a substitution instance of ~(P v Q), even though ~(P v Q) can be true, while ~((A v ~A) v (A v ~A)) is always false.  In this way, validity is irrelevant to the question of whether something is or is not a substitution instance of some formula.

Furthermore, the rule of substitution is such that it has to get applied uniformly throughout a well-formed formula.  In other words, anytime you substitute one variable V in a well-formed formula F with another (usually longer) well-formed formula S anywhere in the formula, you have to substitute V with S everywhere else in F.  It should get noted that F and S need to qualify as well-formed.  In other words, they satisfy the (relevant) definition of a well-formed formula.  If they are not (they aren't actually formulas then), difficulties can result.

For example of how NOT to do a substitution, consider the tautology (p$\rightarrow$(q$\rightarrow$p)).  If we replace the first p with a, and the second with c, then we have (a$\rightarrow$(q$\rightarrow$c)).  But, if a is true, q is true, and c is false, then this formula is false, while (p$\rightarrow$(q$\rightarrow$p)) is always true.  For a correct example, we would substitute p with a everywhere or p with c everywhere, thus obtaining (a$\rightarrow$(q$\rightarrow$a)) or (c$\rightarrow$(q$\rightarrow$c)).

Substitution often plays a key role in working with tautologies, since anytime you (uniformly) substitute a formula in a tautology T with another formula, the resulting formula T' is also a tautology.  This is often part of how axiomatic propositional calculi work, and many axiomatic propositional calculi rely on a rule of substitution.  Those that don't often still use notation in their proof analyses which can get read as using a rule of substitution.